# Finding a feasible solution for a large scale non-standard lp problem.

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research

The initial solution to my problem is not feasible as -ve slack are present in the table. So I tried to remove them by the a process I found on YouTube.
https://youtu.be/LE9Lnl2iXrA
After a no of iterations the -ve slack variables are reduced but not gone fully, but the problem is I reached a point at which there are no +ve numbers in the row containing the    -ve slack element. How do I proceed further. 
I also tried the 2 phase method with artificial variables. That too failed.
The final table at which the problem starts is given here
https://drive.google.com/file/d/19EbgR0yGUwNrFH8-uYYz6mPO7RflC7xo/view?usp=drivesdk

So where did I went wrong? Or do I need to use some other algorithm to solve this?

Comment: Are you certain that the problem is feasible?

Comment: Yes it is as all the variables are unconstrained.

Comment: How can the variables be unconstrained if you have a table of constraints? (That table is a simplex tableau, right?)

Comment: I mean unrestricted variables means they can be both +ve or -ve

Comment: That does not guarantee that the model is feasible.